# Speed limits osm2po

Tags: osm2po

I ran into the problem, that in the US there are very different speed limits depending on each state. So using default values from osm2po.config does not really help (or am I wrong?). For some areas I'd like to adjust those values "manually". To do so I'd need to know which edge took its value from osm2po.config and which took its value from OSM.

Is there a reccomended way to indicate which edge has been attributed by a value from osm2po.config and which has been attributed from values derived from OSM?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

- set your speedlimits in `osm2po.config` to sth. noticeable stupid (like 500mph)
- import your data -> every differing value obviously comes from the osm tags
- do your manual changes
- set the remaining "500mph" to some standard limit per class

Comment: This solution works for sure. Would be cleaner if a flag could be set though. I'm trying to avoid the effort to set all remaining values for every class

Comment: Understandable, but you have to write a "Ref-Table" either way and you can wrap the last point in a script. So the extra effort would be very limited, imho.